# Process Synchronization Coffe Shop Employee and Customer Algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, synchronization, multiprocessing

I am writing a program in C that allows a Coffe Shop of only one employee to serve multiple customers. To do so, I made two processes, (1) a customer process and (2) an employee process.

**My questions are,**

1. Will this algorithm give me correct syncronization without deadlock
   or starvation or any other syncronization problem?
2. Is it necessary to protect shared variables, if yes how?

**More Details:** When a customer arrives, he waits for the employee until it is free, then the customer says Hi, then the employee says Hi back. The employee waits for the customer until he/she decide what to get. After he made the decision, the employee serve the customer, and then each of them do what ever they want.

I used 3 semaphores

```
sem customer = 0;         // Number of customers in the shop
sem readyToTakeOrder = 1; // Employee is free and ready to take order 
sem endOrder = 1;         // Customer finished giving his order
```

My customer algorith was as follow,

```
void customer(){
    customer.signal();
    readyToTakeOrder.wait();
    print("I want a coffee");
    endOrder.signal();
    leave();          // leave the shop
}
```

The employee algorithm,

```
void employee(){
    customer.wait();
    print("How can I help you");
    readyToTakeOrder.signal();
    endOrder.wait();
    serveCoffee();    // make customer's coffee
    leave();          // end serving this customer
}
```

Comment: Where's your fourth semaphore?

Comment: Sorry, I had a forth sempahore that was called mutex to protext shared variables then I removed it.

Comment: @tijko How can i know if there is any syncronization problem in general?